# Momentarily change TextView value on method call android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity comprising of a button and a label. The method on the button click retrieves the current location and updates the text of the textview with the area. I want to know how to momentarily change the text of the textview to "Loading Location" upon the button click, and when it loads the location, update it to the location area.

How to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following via thread:

```
public void setLocationText(){

    //Set text to Loading... text in textview   

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            //Set location text in textview         
       }
    };
    new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Get the required location text
        mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }
    }.start();
}
```